# Java: массив классов

Tags: массивы, классы, java

Возможно ли создать массив (лист или что-то на бодобие этого) подобных Java-классов, которые наследуются от 1 класса (это можно убрать)?

Comment: Что-то вроде этого?

    class A {}
    class B extends A {}
    class C extends A {}

    List<A> listOfA = new ArrayList<A>();
    listOfA.add(new B());
    listOfA.add(new C());

Comment: у Вас не массив классов, а массив объектов.

Comment: @KoVadim, вопрос автора не совсем очевиден, на хэшкоде "списком классов" обычно называют все, что угодно )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь о списке экземпляров `Class<T>`, то это можно сделать через `bounded generic types` и `wildcard`:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
class D {}

List<Class<? extends A>> listOfA = new ArrayList<Class<? extends A>>();
listOfA.add(A.class);
listOfA.add(B.class);
listOfA.add(C.class);
//listOfA.add(D.class); -- класс D не пройдет
```